# Finding the cell reference for a value in a random 5x5 array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 5x5 array with letters A-Y in random locations.  I need to find where a specific letter is within the array.  I was able to get a 1x25 matrix using search, match and isnumber which had a 1 in the location of the desired value but I don't know how to extract that position from the array.

{a, b, c, d, e; f, g, h, i, j; k, l, m, n, o; p, q, r, s, t; u, v, w, x, y}

if i'm looking for the "d" would return

{0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0}

How do I extract that the 'd' was in fourth position or [1,4] of the original array? In the original problem the characters are not in any specific order.  They're totally random.

I'm doing this in an excel spreadsheet, so trying to find a formula that will work rather than VBA code.  isnumber around search to get the 1x25 matrix

Comment: Is your array/matrix in individual cells in Excel?

Comment: Yes, the array is elements are in individual cells in Excel and there are no repeats, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of giving alternatives:

[image]

To get the row: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:E5=B7)*ROW(A1:E5))`

To get the column: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:E5=B7)*COLUMN(A1:E5))`

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- Your letters are each in their own cell
- There are no repeats of letters (or whatever you want to search for), each cell is unique
- Your 5X5 matrix starts in C2
- The value you want to search for is in A2

AGGREGATE is my function of choice here.  It will perform array like operations for formulas 14 and 15.  It can be set up to ignore errors, which will be used to our advantage, and we can pick and choose where in the list of results we want to pull the results from.  AGGREGATE take the form of:

```
AGGREGATE(Formula #, Ignore Option #, range/array, parameter)
```

- Formula 15 will sort the list of results from smallest to largest.  Formula 14 does it from largest to smallest.  provided all entries are unique, it does not matter which of the two is used.
- Option 6 will ignore all errors within the range/array
- For the range/array part, build a list of all the spreadsheet row/column numbers.  Build do the formula once for rows and then repeat it and switch is to columns.  Divide the row or column number by a TRUE/FALSE result.  in this case it will be does the range/array equal your search term.  When sending TRUE/FALSE through a math operation (not all functions) TRUE becomes 1 and FALSE becomes 0.  Dividing by 0 will generate an error.  only rows where your search term are will be divided by 1 leaving the row number unchanged.  Since option 6 ignores all errors, you will be left with a list of row numbers that have your search term.  As long as your cells are all unique this means you will have only 1 row number.
- The parameter part for formulas 14 and 15 is what position from the sorted results you want returned.  In this case the first occurrence is wanted so it should be 1.

Putting this information together tells us that our AGGREGATE formula should be something along the lines of:

```
FOR ROW
AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$G$6)/($C$2:$G$6=$A$2),1)

FOR COLUMN
AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($C$2:$G$6)/($C$2:$G$6=$A$2),1)
```

Now this will tell you what spreasheet column and row you are in.  If you matrix/array started in A1 you would not need to do anything further.  However this solution assumed your matrix started in C2.  Which means your matrix row and column numbers do not match the spreadsheets row and column numbers.  A minor adjustment will need to be made.  Simply subtract the starting position of the matrix and add 1.  This adjustment will make the formula look like:

```
FOR ROW
AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$G$6)/($C$2:$G$6=$A$2),1)-ROW($C$2)+1

FOR COLUMN
AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($C$2:$G$6)/($C$2:$G$6=$A$2),1)-COLUMN($C$2)+1
```

[image: POC]

Answer (score 1):

A nested For Next seems appropriate. Comments in code.

```
Sub finInArray()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr As Variant, z As String, bFoundIt As Boolean

    'dimension array
    ReDim arr(0 To 4, 0 To 4)

    'populate array
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(i, j) = Chr(65 + i + j)
        Next j
    Next i

    'designate char to find
    z = "H"

    'find in array
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If z = arr(i, j) Then
                bFoundIt = True
                'stop looping j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        'if found, stop looping i
        If bFoundIt Then Exit For
    Next i

    'was it found?
    If i <= UBound(arr, 1) And j <= UBound(arr, 2) Then
        Debug.Print z & " found at arr(" & i & ", " & j & ")"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I like the VBA code, but I am not skilled enough at incorporating that into a spreadsheet.  I needed to use the formula over and over in multiple locations.  How would I do that with VBA?  Can that code be turned into a function call or something?  Sorry for my lack of skill at using this answer.  It looks very well thought out.  Thanks!

Comment: That could easily be converted to a user defined function but it's unclear on wat you want returned and for most intents and purposes, a UDF only returns a single value. Do you want to return the row or the column or a range object to the cell containing the found value? Are you dealing with a 5x5 range of cells on the worksheet or a 5x5 variant array in memory?

Comment: i am dealing with a 5x5 range of cells in a worksheet.  Actually, it's a 25x25 array of cells in a worksheet.  I can break it up and deal with it 5x5 blocks.  What I want returned is a row and col of the location where a specific letter is found.  Each cell only contains 0 or 1 letter and every 5x5 group has no repeats ever.  A-Y are represented at most once for each 5x5 block.  Some cells will be blank, but none will have duplicate values and they are never sorted in any certain order.

Comment: So, i'm not very smart on using VBA for working with a worksheet.  I would love to understand on how to apply VBA code like you supplied to work with data in the sheet and manipulate it and return values.  If there is a way to do that I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I like the aggregate, but I wasn't familiar with that before.  Thank you!!

I also found a solution after I posted the question.

```
SUM((MMULT((rowfind_array),--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D",data))))))
```

where rowfind_array is a 1x5 matrix with 1 2 3 4 5  and data is the 5x5 matrix with either letters or blanks in it.  This returns the row number of the letter, if found.

The search, isnumber and the "--" return a 5x5 array with all 0's and a 1 where the searched item was found. Multiplying it by a 5x1 or 1x5 array before or after the result and then summing the final array gives a number 1-5 which indicates my row (or col) number.

So the col number just switch the finder array dimensions and place it after the data array, instead of before.

```
SUM((MMULT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D",data))),colfind_array)))
```

where colfind_array is a 5x1 matrix with 1 2 3 4 5  and data is the 5x5 matrix with either letters or blanks in it.  This returns the col number of the letter, if found.

A simple =if(countif("D",data)=1,... check to see if the letter is there to begin with and I am all done.

I'm using this to find the rows and cols of entries on a 25x25 sudoku puzzle helper.  If the letters are in the 5x5 block it returns the row and col to eliminate the rows and cols for the unanswered squares.  It works pretty well!

If you have any other smart ways to solve this problem, please share.
Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I did an excel spreadsheet once that assisted with the standard 9X9 format.  I had the puzzle on sheet 1, and then on sheet 2 I ran the three standard checks. I used countif to see how many times a specific number occured in either column, row or box.  I then used conditional formatting on the  main sheet to hide the digit when it occurred just once in any of the counts, but I had the entry change bright red if it occurred more than once.  It was not going to solve the puzzle.  Just let you know what the possible entries were for a box.

Comment: Yeah, I've found several for 9x9 sheet solvers/helpers and even a couple for 16x16 sheets solvers, but I have a book of 25x25 sheet puzzles and kept getting stuck.  So, I decided to extend a 9x9 sheet helper that I found on the internet and get some help solving 25x25 without completely just giving me the answer.  If I am stuck I just can get a little boost. I had already done extensions to make a 16x16 sudoku solver, but it used 0-9 and A-F, while the 25x25 uses A-Y.  This complicated my solution and made me rethink the equations.